# How to print DataGridView having dynamically created last row?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I dynamically created the last cell/row in a DataGridView to show the total members count and total amount paid, but when I print the DataGridView, the last cell/row is not printed.

I tried to solve this problem, but I didn't get the correct result. How can I also print the last cell/row?

This my code to show data in DataGridView:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmdshow = new SqlCommand("select Regno,Fullname,Contactno,Address,PaidAmt from NewMember", con);
    SqlDataReader drshow = cmdshow.ExecuteReader();
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(drshow);
    dataGridViewreport.DataSource = dt;

    dataGridViewreport[3, dataGridViewreport.Rows.Count - 1].Value = "Total Sum";
    dataGridViewreport[0, dataGridViewreport.Rows.Count - 1].Value = "Total Members";

    int r;
    for (r = 0; r < dataGridViewreport.Rows.Count - 1; r++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewreport.Rows[r];
    }

    double Total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewreport.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        Total += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridViewreport.Rows[i].Cells["PaidAmt"].Value);

    }
    dataGridViewreport.Rows[dataGridViewreport.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["PaidAmt"].Value = Total;
    dataGridViewreport.Rows[dataGridViewreport.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Fullname"].Value = r;
 }
```

And this code is used for printing the DataGridView:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DGVPrinter printer = new DGVPrinter();
    printer.Title = "Member Report";
    printer.PageNumberInHeader = false;
    printer.PorportionalColumns = true;

    printer.HeaderCellAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    printer.PrintDataGridView(dataGridViewreport);
  }
```

Comment: does the value appear int he grid ?

Comment: You don't need to show commented code, it just clutters the view.